# Faster conversion of Pandas datetime colum to string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a major performance issue with converting Pandas dataframe date columns to string columns. Currently I am working with the code below. The column date_column (generally) contains datetime objects which I would like to transform to more human-readable string by using strftime('%d.%m.%Y'). Because it happened with previous data I used in my model I check if the values are string or NA, i.e. no datetime object. In that case I would like the output to be 'no date'.

Unfortunately my approach is extremely slow. Especially with large data (10m rows and more) it can take up to 1-2 minutes or even longer. Any recommendations with regards to performance improvement is much appreciated. So far I could not find any solutions on stackoverflow.

Thank you!

```
dataframe_input.loc[:,date_column] = (dataframe_input.loc[:,date_column].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') if pd.notnull(x) and not isinstance(x, str) else "no date")).apply(str)
```

Comment: please check pandas builtin strftime function. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is correct to assume that a large number of records will have the same date (which seems likely for a dataset with 10M records), we can leverage that and improve efficiency by not converting the same date to string over and over.

For example, here's how it would look like on per-second data from 2021-01-01 to 2021-02-01 (which is about 2.7M records):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', freq='1s')})
```

Here's with the `strftime` applied to the whole column:

```
%%time
df['dt_str'] = df['dt'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

Output:

```
CPU times: user 8.07 s, sys: 63.9 ms, total: 8.14 s
Wall time: 8.14 s
```

And here's with `map` applied to de-duplicated values:

```
%%time
dts = df['dt'].astype('datetime64[D]').drop_duplicates()
m = pd.Series(dts.dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'), dts)
df['dt_str'] = df['dt'].map(m)
```

Output:

```
CPU times: user 207 ms, sys: 32 ms, total: 239 ms
Wall time: 240 ms
```

It's about 30x faster. Of course, the speedup depends on the number of unique date values -- the higher the number, the less we gain by using this method.

Comment: Awesome, excatly what I was hoping for. It works. Thank you very much!!

Comment: one followup question, how would you handle missing values or non datetime values/object within the column df['dt']?

Comment: I think depends on what you want to achieve, `map` will only use whatever you have in the `m` Series, so if you keep only dates there, other values should map to NaN, which you can later drop/fill with some default value etc. Really more of a question of what is needed for the problem that you're solving